# how to find the github handle of a person QUICKLY?

Tags: github, user-accounts

Is there a quick way to find the handle of a github user when I want to ping him with `@`?

I know I can use `https://github.com/search?q=...&type=users` and I've set a browser shortcut for it,

But can I do it directly from the github editor?

- The editor's autocomplete is not very good.
- The above search is also not very good: you have to put the exact name, no fuzziness is allowed.

I realize there are millions of users on github, but is there some smart userscript to remember my frequent correspondents, and use all users active in the current repo?